# Use of person years experience or another word for combined experience

Tags: word-usage, complex-sentences

I am preparing to write a statement about my previous company's founders experience in my resume and I am having a quandary as to how to write the following:

> ABC Info has been founded by people with more than 80 person years of experience in the marketing industry.

I assume that since the experience doesn't belong to only a single person, here ***person years*** means more than one person's experience combined together.

Is the above sentence is right? or

How can I write this statement properly?

Comment: The unit 'person year' is, I'd say, a candidate snowclone and sounds sensible and inventive. But I doubt that it's 'acceptable' in formal situations. Andy's suggestion, or 'with a [combined] total of over 80 years in marketing', shouldn't raise any eyebrows _or_ cause any headaches.

Comment: Sure, "person-years" is utterly correct and normal and often seen.  I would use a hyphen.  "man-years" sounds more normal, but there's a trend for "non-sexed language" in AmE.  Note too that, very simply, you can leave out the "person" in the sentence and it makes perfect sense and works perfectly.  To repeat, if you're confused by the term, just check out "man-years" (any dictionary or a million examples online), it's the "non-sexed" version of same.

Comment: You would only require person-years over just years if it was known that one of your corporate founders was a wallaby or a vampire and not a person.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this expressed as "with over 80 combined years in marketing".

Comment: i'd say "..with over 80 years of combined experience in.."